# Stylecop-ish validation for c# code written in k&r style

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, stylecop, curly-braces

I'm a big fan of the K&R coding style and I don't really like the Allman style at all. With resharper I can get visual studio to give me good support for K&R as I write the code, but I can't really integrate that into a continous integration system :/

Is there a stylecop "plugin" or a stylecop alternative somewhere that will validate code style according to k&r instead of allman or will I have to write my own code style checker to get something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You've actually given your own answer - Resharper can indeed do this as part of your continuous integration.

If you're using Teamcity for continuous integration, it's built in.

If not, you'll have to wire it up yourself using their [command line utilities](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/command-line.html). Obviously you'll need to feed it your Resharper .DotSettings file with your preferred rules.

Comment: I wasn't aware that Resharpers command line utils actually performed code style validation, that's actually very useful! I'll look in to it right away :)

Comment: While resharper do give a lot of good info with their command line utilities I can't seem to make it validate _code style_ things such as brace placement etc. So I'm not sure that this is the answer to my question sadly :(